# Why this error 'ErrorORA-01810: format code appears twice' occurs

Tags: oracle, plsql

In my oracle function I have a variable of type TIMESTAMP. I extract an xml value and convert it to timestamp but this error occurs. I am giving the code and sample input.
First I declare the variable as following:

```
input_ebasp_created_on TIMESTAMP;
```

Then I extract and put value into it:

```
IF xmlData.existsnode('/employees/employee/ebasp_created_on/text()')>0 THEN
  input_ebasp_created_on:=TO_TIMESTAMP(xmlData.extract('/employees/employee/ebasp_created_on/text()').getstringval(),'DD-MM-YYYY   HH:MM:SS AM');
END IF;
```

If I run this code then this error occurs:

```
ErrorORA-01810: format code appears twice
```

The sample input is: `7-2-2016   11:52:39 AM`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `MM` twice. The second occurrence of `MM` in time part is wrong, as for minutes you use `MI`.

Change your code to

```
IF xmlData.existsnode('/employees/employee/ebasp_created_on/text()')>0 THEN 
  input_ebasp_created_on:=TO_TIMESTAMP(xmlData.extract('/employees/employee/ebasp_created_on/text()').getstringval(),'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'); 

END IF;
```